# Acces the raw wiki page contents in a Dokuwiki Render Plugin

Tags: php, plugins, dokuwiki

I created a plugin and its basic functionalities are working well. It returns always `testing` as you can see in the method `document_end()`.

**But how can I access the plain, raw wiki page content?**

This is my [rawcontent.php](http://dokuwiki.pastebin.com/BMKHPNZ5) file in the corresponding plugin folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. After a deep serach in the code of Dokuwiki I discovered **`rawWiki()`**.

It returns the raw content of a page, the current page name/id is a "global" "constant" named `$ID`.

**Solution:**

```
global $ID;
return rawWiki($ID);
```