# Options to update dokuwiki page contents programmatically

Tags: automation, dokuwiki

SOers!

I am having some issues with DokuWiki in the terms of content modification automatiozation. My need is to update page programmatically, in my case the data source would be text file, that would be regex parsed and the output would be inserted into DokuWiki page.

Up to this moment, I have not found anything related to this feature, but I really doubt I am only one having need for such stuff, so invetning bycicle again is not a best way here :)

Currently there is something in this Question:

[Acces the raw wiki page contents in a Dokuwiki Render Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958070/acces-the-raw-wiki-page-contents-in-a-dokuwiki-render-plugin)

My sub-Question is - How can I use it to do content modifications? I had mo time to go through whole dokuwiki source code, so I am hoping there are some lego blocks that I could simply attach together to make it happen w/o developing new interfaces etc.

Thanks a lot for any response!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. modify page contents on disk direcly. all your pages are in `data/pages/pagename.txt` as raw text files. you will not have any revision history this way
2. use the XMLRPC API to access and update your pages. See http://www.dokuwiki.org/devel:xmlrpc
3. use the dwpage command line tool to checkout, then modify, then checkin your pagedata again. See http://www.dokuwiki.org/cli#dwpagephp

Comment: Hmm. Then I have final Qiestion: How to modify specific table in specified table? Is there any option or Only way to do it is to parse page as some kind of html, mody data, and them old page replace with modified ( as page.txt, not asonly needed changes )? Currently I focus on updating some tables and their data ...

Comment: A pity that this well upvoted answer was never accepted. Doing so would help others who read the question in future